# Pivoting a Series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, series

I have a series that looks like this:

```
Area        Classification         Samples
88          500m-1bi               34
94          500m-1bi               112
09          500m-1bi               912
            >1bi                   31
81          <1m                    6574
87          100-500m               12
...
```

I want that the 'Classification' labels become columns and that 'Samples' become the values, so it looks like this:

```
Area       <1m    100-500m     500-1bi      >1bi  
88                             34
94                             112
09                             912          31
81         6574
87                12
...
```

I've tried:

```
df.pivot(columns='Classification', values='Samples')
```

But when I do that, I get `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'pivot'`.

So I tried to turn it into a Dataframe:

```
df.to_frame().pivot(columns='Classification', values='Samples')
```

In this case I get:

```
KeyError: 'Classification'
```

Any idea on how to solve it?

** EDIT **

This series was obtained from a groupby function:

```
df=df.groupby(['Area','Classification']).agg('count').sort_values('Samples')['Samples']
```

Comment: How do you create said series? Series are usually 1 dimensional.... what do you get when you do `df.values`

Comment: I'm getting it out of a groupby function:         df=df.groupby(['Area','Classification']).agg('count').sort_values('code')['code']. The "samples" is actually "code", I used samples cause it seemed simpler to understand

Comment: what happens if you just do `df.unstack()` (where df is the series post-agg)

Comment: When I do df.values I get [  34    112    912    ...]

Comment: Ohhhhh all I needed to do is df.unstack(). Worked perfectly. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly modified df for this example. Added the 10 in Area to fill in the gap:

```
Area        Classification         Samples
88          500m-1bi               34
94          500m-1bi               112
09          500m-1bi               912
10          >1bi                   31
81          <1m                    6574
87          100-500m               12
```

You need to set the index then unstack:

```
df.set_index(['Area', 'Classification']).unstack()
```

Output:

```
                Samples                       
Classification 100-500m 500m-1bi     <1m  >1bi
Area                                          
9                   NaN    912.0     NaN   NaN
10                  NaN      NaN     NaN  31.0
81                  NaN      NaN  6574.0   NaN
87                 12.0      NaN     NaN   NaN
88                  NaN     34.0     NaN   NaN
94                  NaN    112.0     NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @ChuHo! However I'm getting AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'.

Comment: You need to change your series to a dataframe. Try `df = pd.DataFrame('your_series_here')`

Comment: Did it. Now I'm getting: KeyError: 'Area'

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you have **more columns** in your dataframe and you want to unstack just with respect to 'Samples' feature:

```
copy = df.set_index(['Area', 'Classification']) # Multi-Index
result = copy['Samples'].unstack() # unstack separately
```

Then you can put everything together (adding untouched columns) by using [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) (since you worked with a copy of your df you don't have trouble in dealing with the index now).

```
df = pd.concat([df, result], axis=1)
```

'ignore_index' is False by defult so you're done.